# Disable tex interpreter in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, interpreter

I would like to produce plots using matplotlib (through anaconda-spider installed on os x yosemite) and put labels on it not interpreted by tex.
Here is the sample code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
my_rc_param = {'text.usetex': False}
pp.figure()
pp.rcParams.update(my_rc_param)
pp.plot(range(10))
pp.xlabel('$x$')
```

I would like to see exactly the string $x$ as x label. In turn, I get the math-mode latex x.
I have also tried, unsuccessfully, to put the following preamble:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=False)
```

Is there a way to force a plain interpreter? 
Or should I consider this as a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting any latex mode. You are simply using the [mathtex](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#mathtext-tutorial) feature of matplotlib. Using latex is a different thing. I checked whether it is possible to switch off mathtex for matplotlib, and there is a quiet recent issue on this ([see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4938)). However, the way to sort out this problem consist is avoiding the math just escaping the $ symbol with '\':

```
pp.xlabel('\$x\$')
```

Just remove all the stuff related to the text.usetex as you are trying to do a complete different thing here.