# Dollar Sign with Thousands Comma Tick Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, display, number-formatting, dollar-sign

Given the following bar chart:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': [1000,2000]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2, 2))

df.plot(kind='bar', x='A', y='B',
        align='center', width=.5, edgecolor='none', 
        color='grey', ax=ax)
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'd like to display the y-tick labels as thousands of dollars like this:

$2,000

I know I can use this to add a dollar sign:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
fmt = '$%.0f'
tick = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)
```

...and this to add a comma:

```
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(
     mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

...but how do I get both?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `StrMethodFormatter`, which uses the `str.format()` specification mini-language.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': [1000,2000]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2, 2))
df.plot(kind='bar', x='A', y='B',
        align='center', width=.5, edgecolor='none', 
        color='grey', ax=ax)

fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick) 
plt.xticks(rotation=25)

plt.show()
```

[image: Both commas and dollar signs]

Comment: is there away to make it 1K,2K,.. instead?

Comment: Worth noting the annoyingly confusing method names: `StrMethodFormatter` and `FormatStrFormatter`

Comment: For adding thousands, you could do this: define a function: `currency = lambda x, pos: "${x:,.0f}k".format(x * 1e-3)` and pass the function in the formatter `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(currency) `

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `get_yticks()` to get an array of the values displayed on the y-axis (0, 500, 1000, etc.) and the `set_yticklabels()` to set the formatted value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B'], 'B': [1000,2000]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(2, 2))

df.plot(kind='bar', x='A', y='B', align='center', width=.5, edgecolor='none', 
        color='grey', ax=ax)

--------------------Added code--------------------------
# getting the array of values of y-axis
ticks = ax.get_yticks()
# formatted the values into strings beginning with dollar sign
new_labels = [f'${int(amt)}' for amt in ticks]
# Set the new labels
ax.set_yticklabels(new_labels)
-------------------------------------------------------
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
plt.show()
```