# How to add currency format to matplotlib.pyplot.text?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to change the format of the text created with `matplotlib.pyplot.text` - That I'm adding the text above each bar in a bar plot. But I dont know how. I have tried the approach suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152356/matplotlib-dollar-sign-with-thousands-comma-tick-labels), was able to change the format on the y axis, but had no success with the text boxes.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIcgO.png)

This is the method used in the linked question (which I also used for my y axis):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 5))
fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)
```

And this is code that I'm using to create the text:

```
for i in range(len(cost_tbl)):
    ax.text(i-0.2, cost_tbl[i, 2]+18000, str(int(cost_tbl[i, 2])), rotation=60)
```

Comment: `'${x:,.0f}'.format(x=int(cost_tbl[i, 2]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to do it. I will explain below with a sample data since you did not provide one.

**First**: Simply adding a string `$` to your text

- `ax.text(i, height[i]+100000, '$'+str(int(height[i])), rotation=60)`

**Second** Using your `fmt = '${x:,.0f}'` *without* `x`

- `ax.text(i, height[i]+100000, '${:,.0f}'.format(height[i]), rotation=60)`

---

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 5))
height = np.random.randint(100000, 500000, 10)
plt.bar(range(10), height)

fmt = '${x:,.0f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick)

for i in range(10):
#     ax.text(i, height[i]+5, '$'+str(int(height[i])), rotation=60)
    ax.text(i, height[i]+100000, '${:,.0f}'.format(height[i]), rotation=60)

plt.ylim(0, max(height)*1.5)
```

[image]