# Format y-axis as Trillions of U.S. dollars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Here's a Python program which does the following:

- Makes an API call to treasury.gov to retrieve data
- Stores the data in a Pandas dataframe
- Plots the data

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

page_size = 10000

url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v2/accounting/od/debt_to_penny'

url_params = f'?page[size]={page_size}'

response = requests.get(url + url_params)

result_json = response.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(result_json['data'])

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['record_date'])

rows = df[df['debt_held_public_amt'] != 'null']

rows['debt_held_public_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(rows['debt_held_public_amt'])

plt.ion()

rows.plot(x='record_date', y='debt_held_public_amt', kind='line', rot=90)
```

Here's the resulting chart that I get:

[image]

## Question

The `debt_held_public_amt` is in U.S. dollars:

[image]

What's a good way to format the y-axis as trillions of U.S. dollars?

Comment: [How to format axis tick labels from number to thousands or Millions (125,436 to 125.4K)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53747298/7758804) [Dollar Sign with Thousands Comma Tick Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38152356/7758804)

Comment: Thank you for those references @TrentonMcKinney. I've posted an answer based on the suggestions there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381899/268581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked around for someone who did this in a nice looking way, and I found [this graph](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:National_debt_of_the_United_States.webp) on Wikipedia.

I decided to do that.

First, I converted the amount to a number. I found that your code for doing this conversion didn't work for me - it created a SettingWithCopy warning.

```py
rows = df[df['debt_held_public_amt'] != 'null'].copy()
rows['debt_held_public_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(rows['debt_held_public_amt'])
```

Next, I did a unit conversion, and set the tick format to put '$ T' around each number.

```py
rows['debt_held_public_amt_tr'] = rows['debt_held_public_amt'] / 1e12
ax = rows.plot(x='record_date', y='debt_held_public_amt_tr', kind='line', rot=90)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter('${x:.0f} T')
```

See also [Dollar ticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/dollar_ticks.html) from the matplotlib documentation.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you Nick!

Comment: And thank you for the `.copy()` suggestion.  Yup, I noticed the warning as well.

Comment: Here's another approach which doesn't use the extra column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77381899/268581

Comment: @dharmatech Nice - that seems like a more elegant option.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach which uses `FuncFormatter`.

This approach avoids the use of an extra column for the trillions values.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
page_size = 10000

url = 'https://api.fiscaldata.treasury.gov/services/api/fiscal_service/v2/accounting/od/debt_to_penny'

url_params = f'?page[size]={page_size}'

response = requests.get(url + url_params)

result_json = response.json()
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

df = pd.DataFrame(result_json['data'])

df['record_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['record_date'])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
plt.ion()
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

df['debt_held_public_amt'] = pd.to_numeric(df['debt_held_public_amt'], errors='coerce')

plt.ion()

ax = df.plot(x='record_date', y=['debt_held_public_amt', 'intragov_hold_amt', 'tot_pub_debt_out_amt'], kind='line', rot=90)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '$' + '{:1.0f}'.format(x/1000/1000/1000/1000) + 'T'))
```

[image]